# How make to fill space after column was hidden in column chart using highchart?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, highcharts

Is there way to fill space after one column was hidden by clicking on legend item?

```
<div id="container" style="height: 300px"></div>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.src.js"></script>

    var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({

    chart: {
        type: 'column',
        renderTo: 'container'
    },

    "title":{  
      "text":"TITLE",
      "align":"left"
   },
   "subtitle":{  
      "text":"Subtitle Text",
      "align":"left",
      "style":{  
         "paddingBottom":"20px"
      }
   },
   "xAxis":{  
      "categories":[  
         "Category1",
         "Category2",
         "Category3",
         "Category4",
         "Category5"
      ],
      "crosshair":true,
      "title":{  

      },
      "labels":{  
         "enabled":false,
         "format":"{value}"
      }
   },
   "yAxis":{  
      "min":0,
      "title":{  
         "text":"Meters"
      },
      "labels":{  
         "format":"{value}"
      }
   },
   "tooltip":{  
      "enabled":true,
      "headerFormat":"<span style=\"font-size:10px\">{point.key}</span><br/>",
      "shared":true,
      "useHTML":true
   },
   "legend":{  
      "enabled":true,
      "align":"left",
      "useHTML":true
   },
   "plotOptions":{  
      "column":{  
         "pointPadding":0.2,
         "borderWidth":0,
         "dataLabels":{  
            "enabled":true,
            "format":"{point.y:.2f} ",
            "style":{  
               "textShadow":0
            }
         }
      },
      "series":{  
         "grouping":false
      }
   },
    "series":[  
      {  
         "name":"Category1",
         "data":[  
            {  
               "name":"Category1",
               "y":45,
               "x":0
            }
         ]
      },
      {  
         "name":"Category2",
         "data":[  
            {  
               "name":"Category2",
               "y":43,
               "x":1
            }
         ]
      },
      {  
         "name":"Category3",
         "data":[  
            {  
               "name":"Category3",
               "y":43,
               "x":2
            }
         ]
      },
      {  
         "name":"Category4",
         "data":[  
            {  
               "name":"Category4",
               "y":42,
               "x":3
            }
         ]
      },
      {  
         "name":"Category5",
         "data":[  
            {  
               "name":"Category5",
               "y":42,
               "x":4
            }
         ]
      },
      {  
         "name":"",
         "data":[  
            {  

            }
         ],
         "visible":false,
         "showInLegend":false,
         "exporting":false
      },
      {  
         "name":"Bla bla bla",
         "data":[  
            45,
            43,
            43,
            42,
            42
         ],
         "showInLegend":false,
         "visible":false,
         "exporting":true
      }
   ],
   "exporting":{  
      "enabled":false,
      "chartOptions":{  
         "legend":{  
            "enabled":true,
            "maxHeight":null,
            "itemStyle":{  
               "fontFamily":"Arial"
            }
         }
      }
   },
   "loading":{  
      "style":{  
         "opacity":0.9
      }
   },
   "drilldown":{  
      "drillUpButton":{  
         "theme":{  
            "style":{  
               "display":"none"
            }
         }
      }
   }
});
```

[Here is live example](http://jsfiddle.net/whFvA/103/).

When I click on first or last legend item, then chart are redrawing, but it doesn't happening when I clicked on a middle legend item? It's a bug or feature? And how I can change this behavior for middle legend items to they able also throw the event redrawing  the chart?

Thanks advance

Comment: On your xAxis you have an extremes that are changing when you are hiding or showing first and last point. When you are changing middle points, extremes aren't changing. And I don't think they should change.  You can redraw your chart manually by using chart.redraw(), and you can change your extremes manually by using Axis.setExtremes().

Comment: So, I've tried that way, but without success, because I cannot fill space of hidden column, just change scale of chart. Also, same result I can achieve using chart.series[2].remove(true), but in this case legend item is also removed. Maybe you know how I can leave legend item without changes, only remove a related series?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could set and update breaks for xAxis to hide the empty space:

http://jsfiddle.net/a4vcye4p/1/

```
  events: {
    legendItemClick: function() {
      var series = this,
        seriesIndex = series._i,
        xAxis = series.xAxis,
        newBreaks = [];
      if (series.visible) {
        newBreaks = xAxis.options.breaks;
        newBreaks.push({
          from: seriesIndex,
          to: seriesIndex + 1,
          seriesIndex: seriesIndex
        });
      } else {
        Highcharts.each(xAxis.options.breaks, function(br) {
          if (br.seriesIndex !== seriesIndex) {
            newBreaks.push(br);
          }
        });
      }
      xAxis.update({
        breaks: newBreaks
      });
    }
  }
```

Comment: It's amazing! Could you say, there are some alternatives for highcharts@4.1.7?

Comment: @slesh This solution works when using version 4.1.7 of Highcharts and the broken-axis module - http://jsfiddle.net/a4vcye4p/2/

Comment: Ohh, sorry! I did not notice that dependencies, my bad.

Comment: Hi, @Kacper Madej. I've faced the problem with your code but couldn't manage it by myself, but it seems that problem is floating number value of **x** coordinate(_value parameter_) here highcharts.src.js:2924. Could you help me please. Here is [live example](https://jsfiddle.net/ywsvo2pc/2/) of the issue. To reproduce the issue
uncheck values on graph: _iphone, ipad, N/A, sm-g935f, sm-g930f, android 2.0, iphone 6, sm-g920f, sm-g9005_. Actual result:
after _sm-g9005_ is unchecked, errors in console are displayed. Maybe you could advise some workaround? Thanks a lot.

Comment: [Update](https://jsfiddle.net/ywsvo2pc/3/) to newest versions didn't help.

Comment: @slesh I am unable to reproduce the steps - series names are different in the demo than in you comment. Please provide another demo or steps.

Comment: Hi, @Kacper Madej. Sorry, I forgot to say that error is displayed in the browser console. Here is example [before click](http://storage2.static.itmages.com/i/17/0718/h_1500397619_4467052_f8815b658d.png) on sm-g9005 and [after](http://storage8.static.itmages.com/i/17/0718/h_1500397699_6556834_daf844f64d.png). But I couldn't reproduce the issue with previous dummy example. Maybe problem in the data...

Comment: I made mistake, after update to last version the problem has gone. [4.1.7 demo](https://jsfiddle.net/ywsvo2pc/6/) and [latest version demo](http://jsfiddle.net/a4vcye4p/1/). But I am not enable to update. It will be fine to find some workaround.

Comment: @slesh Here's a working demo for version 4.1.7: https://jsfiddle.net/qyuhxuzk/ I have also adjusted breaks size, so categories (axis labels) are hiding correctly.

Comment: thanks a lot for your time and help! You're rock! Is it bug or not? Could you please tell me in short what was the problem?

Comment: @slesh Might be a bug in 4.1.7, but it's not appearing in 5.0.12 (current), so it was resolved. In short: some paths were having NaN instead of numbers. I wasn't debugging the issue since it's not in newer versions - I was only working around it.